# Javascript button on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a button in my slider, I did it with an "a" tag but it can't be selected and does't work as a link.

I found this code in the web, but I think this code is very complex, I cannot figure out where to write the correct code to have a button.

The button I added only appears in the first slide, however I need to add a button on each slide.

```js
var slideIndex,slides,dots,captionText;
function initGallery(){
 // 1 para ocultar y mostrar imageHolder con opasity 0
    slideIndex = 0;
    slides=document.getElementsByClassName("imageHolder"); // slides=4
    slides[slideIndex].style.opacity=1;
 
    // 2 para mostrar las letras 
    captionText=document.querySelector(".captionTextHolder .captionText");
    captionText.innerText=slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;

    // 3 disable nextPrevBtn if slide count is one
    if(slides.length<2){
        var nextPrevBtns=document.querySelector(".leftArrow,.rightArrow");
        nextPrevBtns.style.display="none";
        for (i = 0; i < nextPrevBtn.length; i++) {
            nextPrevBtn[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }

    // 4 add dots
    dots=[];
    var dotsContainer=document.getElementById("dotsContainer"),i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        var dot=document.createElement("span");
        dot.classList.add("dots");
        dotsContainer.append(dot);
        dot.setAttribute("onclick","moveSlide("+i+")");
        dots.push(dot);
    }
    dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}

// botones de izquierda y derecha
initGallery();
function plusSlides(n) {
    moveSlide(slideIndex+n);
}
function moveSlide(n){
    var i;
    var current,next;
    var moveSlideAnimClass={
          forCurrent:"",
          forNext:""
    };
    var slideTextAnimClass;
    if(n>slideIndex) {
        if(n >= slides.length){n=0;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveLeftCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveLeftNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromTop";
    }else if(n<slideIndex){
        if(n<0){n=slides.length-1;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveRightCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveRightPrevSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromBottom";
    }

    if(n!=slideIndex){
        next = slides[n];
        current=slides[slideIndex];
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].className = "imageHolder";
            slides[i].style.opacity=0;
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
        next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
        slideIndex=n;
        captionText.style.display="none";
        captionText.className="captionText "+slideTextAnimClass;
        captionText.innerText=slides[n].querySelector(".captionText").innerText;
        captionText.style.display="block";
    }

}
var timer=null;
function setTimer(){
    timer=setInterval(function () {
        plusSlides(1) ;
    },6000);
}
setTimer();
function playPauseSlides() {
    var playPauseBtn=document.getElementById("playPause");
    if(timer==null){
        setTimer();
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="0px"
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer=null;
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="-33px"
    }
}
```

```css
.galleryContainer{
 top: 0px;
 position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 580px;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: red;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer{
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 1600px;
 align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: relative;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(/img/playPause.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
 top: 90%;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1600px;
    height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .captionText{
    display: none;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .btnSlider{
    position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 220px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 left: 50%;
 top: 350px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #FF0000;
 border-radius: 15px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 color: red;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    width: 50px;
    background: #00000036;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    height: 72px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow:hover,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow:hover{
    background: #000000a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowLeft{
    transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowRight{
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: red;
 font-family: "Nunito";
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder>.captionText{
    margin: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer{
 position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 bottom: 5%;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:background-color 0.5s;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:hover,.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots.active{
    background-color: #717171;;
}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftNextSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftNext;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveLeftCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveLeftNext {
    from {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightPrevSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightPrev;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveRightPrev {
    from {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.slideTextFromBottom {
    animation-name: slideTextFromBottom;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromBottom {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: 100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}
.slideTextFromTop {
    animation-name: slideTextFromTop;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromTop {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: -100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
     <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div class="slideShowContainer">
            <div id="playPause" onclick="playPauseSlides()"></div>
            <div onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="nextPrevBtn leftArrow"><span class="arrow arrowLeft"></span></div>
            <div onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="nextPrevBtn rightArrow"><span class="arrow arrowRight"></span></div>
            <div class="captionTextHolder"><p class="captionText slideTextFromTop"></p></div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
    <a href="#" class="captionText">Todo lo que necesitas en un solo lugar</a>
    <a href="#" class="btnSlider">Mas informacion</a>
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-02</p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-03</p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-04</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dotsContainer"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You might have a z-index problem but there's not enough info to know for sure.

Comment: please add your HTML/CSS

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answers! here you can view the code: https://codepen.io/carlos-ojeda/pen/KbXOKv

Comment: Carlos, please can you edit and add code here, if you use links these often disappear and the answer become non useful for others in the future. It is also unreasonable to ask people to go off site to help.

Comment: Ok I added the code in this site, thank you for the good advise.

Comment: Do you want `mas informacion` button on all pages? I that's the case then you will have to create `btnSlider` element inside all `imageHolder` elements

Comment: Yea, I knew that, thank you. I want the "a" tag to works as a link or button, but in my code it can't even be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done and works** (Again!!!). I move links in div, and replace .innerText selector with .innerHTML (but links now look like links, so  you have to style them). Yeah, it can be simpler, but this works too.

```js
var slideIndex,slides,dots,captionText;
function initGallery(){
 // 1 para ocultar y mostrar imageHolder con opasity 0
    slideIndex = 0;
    slides=document.getElementsByClassName("imageHolder"); // slides=4
    slides[slideIndex].style.opacity=1;
 
    // 2 para mostrar las letras 
    captionText=document.querySelector(".captionTextHolder .captionText");
    captionText.innerHTML=slides[slideIndex].querySelector(".captionText").innerHTML;

    // 3 disable nextPrevBtn if slide count is one
    if(slides.length<2){
        var nextPrevBtns=document.querySelector(".leftArrow,.rightArrow");
        nextPrevBtns.style.display="none";
        for (i = 0; i < nextPrevBtn.length; i++) {
            nextPrevBtn[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }

    // 4 add dots
    dots=[];
    var dotsContainer=document.getElementById("dotsContainer"),i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        var dot=document.createElement("span");
        dot.classList.add("dots");
        dotsContainer.append(dot);
        dot.setAttribute("onclick","moveSlide("+i+")");
        dots.push(dot);
    }
    dots[slideIndex].classList.add("active");
}

// botones de izquierda y derecha
initGallery();
function plusSlides(n) {
    moveSlide(slideIndex+n);
}
function moveSlide(n){
    var i;
    var current,next;
    var moveSlideAnimClass={
          forCurrent:"",
          forNext:""
    };
    var slideTextAnimClass;
    if(n>slideIndex) {
        if(n >= slides.length){n=0;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveLeftCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveLeftNextSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromTop";
    }else if(n<slideIndex){
        if(n<0){n=slides.length-1;}
        moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent="moveRightCurrentSlide";
        moveSlideAnimClass.forNext="moveRightPrevSlide";
        slideTextAnimClass="slideTextFromBottom";
    }

    if(n!=slideIndex){
        next = slides[n];
        current=slides[slideIndex];
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].className = "imageHolder";
            slides[i].style.opacity=0;
            dots[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        current.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forCurrent);
        next.classList.add(moveSlideAnimClass.forNext);
        dots[n].classList.add("active");
        slideIndex=n;
        captionText.style.display="none";
        captionText.className="captionText "+slideTextAnimClass;
        captionText.innerHTML=slides[n].querySelector(".captionText").innerHTML;
        captionText.style.display="block";
    }
document.getElementsByClassName("captionTextHolder")[0].style.animation = "slideTextFromTop 1s";
setTimeout(function () { document.getElementsByClassName("captionTextHolder")[0].style.animation = "";} ,1000);
setTimeout(function() {document.getElementsByClassName('moveLeftCurrentSlide')[0].style.zIndex = 0;}, 500);
}
var timer=null;
function setTimer(){
    timer=setInterval(function () {
        plusSlides(1) ;
    },6000);
}
setTimer();
function playPauseSlides() {
    var playPauseBtn=document.getElementById("playPause");
    if(timer==null){
        setTimer();
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="0px"
    }else{
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer=null;
        playPauseBtn.style.backgroundPositionY="-33px"
    }
}
```

```css
.galleryContainer{
 top: 0px;
 position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 580px;
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color: red;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer{
    width: 100%;
 max-width: 1600px;
 align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    position: relative;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(/img/playPause.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 5;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
 top: 90%;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer #playPause:hover{
    opacity: .7;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1600px;
    height: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .captionText{
    display: none;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .imageHolder .btnSlider{
    position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 220px;
 height: 40px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 left: 50%;
 top: 350px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 15px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 color: white;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    width: 50px;
    background: #00000036;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    height: 72px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow{
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .leftArrow:hover,.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer .rightArrow:hover{
    background: #000000a8;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid white;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowLeft{
    transform: rotateZ(-135deg);
}
.galleryContainer .arrow.arrowRight{
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
 font-family: "Nunito";
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.galleryContainer .slideShowContainer>.captionTextHolder>.captionText{
    margin: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer{
 position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    height: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 bottom: 5%;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition:background-color 0.5s;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots:hover,.galleryContainer #dotsContainer .dots.active{
    background-color: #717171;;
}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveLeftNextSlide{
    animation-name: moveLeftNext;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveLeftCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveLeftNext {
    from {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightCurrentSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightCurrent;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
.galleryContainer .moveRightPrevSlide{
    animation-name: moveRightPrev;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes moveRightCurrent {
    from {margin-left: 0;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 100%;opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes moveRightPrev {
    from {margin-left: -100%;opacity: 1;}
    to {margin-left: 0%;opacity: 1;}
}
.slideTextFromBottom {
    animation-name: slideTextFromBottom;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromBottom {
    from {opacity: 0;margin-top: 100px}
    to {opacity: 1;margin-top: 0px;}
}
.slideTextFromTop {
    animation-name: slideTextFromTop;
    animation-duration: 0.7s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@keyframes slideTextFromTop {
    from {padding-bottom: 90%;}
    to {padding-bottom: 0;}
}
```

```html
     <div class="galleryContainer">
        <div class="slideShowContainer">
            <div id="playPause" onclick="playPauseSlides()"></div>
            <div onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="nextPrevBtn leftArrow"><span class="arrow arrowLeft"></span></div>
            <div onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="nextPrevBtn rightArrow"><span class="arrow arrowRight"></span></div>
            <div class="captionTextHolder"><p class="captionText slideTextFromTop"></p></div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
    <div class="captionText"><a href="#">Todo lo que necesitas en un solo lugar</a><br><br>
    <a href="#">Mas informacion</a>
            </div></div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-02</p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-03</p>
            </div>
            <div class="imageHolder">
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/1600/500/?random">
                <p class="captionText">Caption Text-04</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="dotsContainer"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! last question: do you think that it could be possible to have the text and button animation, that moves from top to bottom, of the first example?

Comment: Nearly everthing is posible, so yes, but there will be lot of work :-)

Comment: Any hint? I think my code is redundant and extensive, I think it could be simpler.

Comment: @CarlosOjeda I thought it would be harder. Yes, of course, it can be simpler.

Comment: Nice! I wish I could code like you some day. Now almost everything is working perfectly, nonetheless when you see the last slide, and when it turn back to the first slide, appears a small line at the left side, something like the image does not fill the entire slide. I think it could be a bug in the JavaScript code, what do you think?